# How to print php response JSON response

Tags: android, json

How to print php response json response in android?

I am android developer but I don't have any idea about json parsing.

```
   {
      "details": [
        {
          "p_id": "19",
          "cat_id": "1",
          "p_name": "Papad",
          "p_namecode": "[01]Papad",
          "p_image": 
          "p_price": "20",
          "p_quantity": "2",
          "p_code": "25",
         "p_discount": "10",
         "p_packing": "2",
         "p_type": "small",
        "p_status": "1",
      "p": [
         {
      "q_id": "16",
      "p_id": "19",
      "q_weight": "25-gm",
      "q_price": "150",
      "q_beg": "50 bunch",
      "q_status": "1"
         },
         {
      "q_id": "17",
      "p_id": "19",
      "q_weight": "50-gm",
      "q_price": "200",
      "q_beg": "50-bunch",
      "q_status": "1"
         }
       ]
      },

    {
  "p_id": "23",
  "cat_id": "1",
  "p_name": "Palak Papad",
  "p_namecode": "[03]Palak",
  "p_image": 
  "p_price": "200",
  "p_quantity": "5",
  "p_code": "02",
  "p_discount": "15",
  "p_packing": "4",
  "p_type": "small",
  "p_status": "1",
  "p": [
    {
      "q_id": "19",
      "p_id": "23",
      "q_weight": "50- gm",
      "q_price": "15",
      "q_beg": "50 bunch",
      "q_status": "1"
    },
    {
      "q_id": "20",
      "p_id": "23",
      "q_weight": "1-kg",
      "q_price": "30",
      "q_beg": "50 bunch",
      "q_status": "1"
    }
  ]
}
],
 "success": true,
 "message": "Category and Sub Category"
}
```

Comment: Use https://github.com/google/gson for json data parsing

Answer (score 0):

Try this for json data parsing

```
String jsonResult = {JSON-RESULT-IN-STRING};
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

boolean success = data.getBoolean("success");
String message = data.getString("message");

JSONArray detailArray = new JSONArray(data.getString("details"))

for (int i=0; i<detailArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject detail = detailArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String pID = detail.getString("p_id");
    String catID = detail.getString("cat_id");
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand your JSON structure. You need GSON gradle for easy to convert your PHP response to java class object.

add this line in app level gradle.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

To understand your JSON data see image below. It is an exact representation of your data.

[image]

Your JSON data contains an `array of Details`, a boolean value `success` and String called `message`. But your Detail array contains another array called `p`. for better understanding see image below.

[image]

Now we are ready to go.

Create Java class `P` as I created below.

```
public class P {
    public int q_id;
    public int p_id;
    public String q_weight;
    public int q_price;
    public String q_beg;
    public int q_status;
}
```

Create new java class Detail. see carefully and create a complete class. you can take reference from the first image.

```
public class Detail {

    public int p_id;
    public int cat_id;
    public String p_name;
    public String p_namecode;
    .
    .
    .
    public int p_status;
    public ArrayList<P> p;
}
```

Now we need a final class you can name it anything.

```
public class Product {
    public ArrayList<Detail> details;
    public boolean success;
    public String message;
}
```

Now, whenever you receive your PHP response string you can convert it into java object like this.

```
Product d = new Product();
String response = "your_php_response_goes here";
Gson gson = new Gson();
d = gson.fromJson(response, Product.class);
```

Your whole response data is inside `d` object. To retrieve data you can do like this.

```
String p_name = d.details.get(0).p_name;
int p_quantity = d.deatails.get(0).p_quantity;
```